# AttachUserPolicy from .NET SDK

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-iam

I'm creating a new AWS user using the SDK.  I'm able to create it, and retrieve the Access and Secret keys just fine.  But I also want to attach an existing policy to the new user, presumably with this command

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_AttachUserPolicy.html

Does this method exist somewhere within the .NET SDK?  I can't find it after a maddening amount of searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [AmazonIdentityManagementServiceClient.AttachUserPolicy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/items/MIAM_IAMServiceAttachUserPolicy_AttachUserPolicyRequestNET4_5.html).

**Signature:**

```
public virtual AttachUserPolicyResponse AttachUserPolicy(AttachUserPolicyRequest request)
```

**Request:**

- [Amazon.IdentityManagement.Model.AttachUserPolicyRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/items/TIAMAttachUserPolicyRequest_NET4_5.html)

**Response:**

- [Amazon.IdentityManagement.Model.AttachUserPolicyResponse](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/items/TIAMAttachUserPolicyResponse_NET4_5.html)

There's also an [async version](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/items/MIAM_IAMServiceAttachUserPolicyAsync_AttachUserPolicyRequest_CancellationTokenNET4_5.html), if you're interested.

Comment: Do I need to reference a new DLL or something?! `Error 1 'Amazon.IdentityManagement.AmazonIdentityManagementServiceClient' does not contain a definition for 'AttachUserPolicy' and no extension method 'AttachUserPolicy' accepting a first argument of type 'Amazon.IdentityManagement.AmazonIdentityManagementServiceClient' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`